# complexity analysis of recursive code

Tags: time-complexity, master-theorem

```
 function(int n)
 {
  if(n<=1)
  return;
  for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
  function(n-1);
 }
```

now to calculate complexity of this question we have to use master theorem of subtraction.Now I deduced the recurrence relation which turns out to be `T(n)=c+3T(n-1)` for `n>1`.But how to calculate complexity of this question using master theorem of subtraction since in master theorem `f(n)=O(n^d)` where d>0.But here there it is c which is a constant term and not of the format `O(n^d)`.So how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The master's theorem for subtract and conquer recurrences applies to recurrences of the form

```
T(n) = aT(n-b) + f(n). iff f(n) in O(n^d) for some d >= 0
```

In this particular case, you have the following:

```
a = 3, b = 1, f(n) = c.
```

Let `d = 0, f(n)` is in `O(n^d) = O(1)` since c is a constant.

So we can apply the master's theorem now

Thus `T(n)` is in `O(n^d * a^(n/b))` since `a > 1`

Now plug in our values and we get

```
T(n) in O(n^0 * 3^(n/1)) <=> O(3^n)
```

Useful source: https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~saunders/courses/320/10f/recurrence-relations.pdf